# Node : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, oracle

Node service select 700000 row of data from a table and inset to another table.

```js
async function fetchData(lastSyncDate: string) {
    var result;
    if (!lastSyncDate)
        result = await executeOracleSelect(`select * from table1 order by lastupdated_dt`) as Array<{ [key: string]: any }>
    else {
        var query = `select * from table1 where lastupdated_dt> to_date('${lastSyncDate}','DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') order by lastupdated_dt`;
        result = await executeOracleSelect(query) as Array<{ [key: string]: any }>
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
(node:11752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: This code alone cannot be responsible for that error. More context needed.

Comment: For that much data, use a [ResultSet](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#resultsethandling).  Also - very important - use a [bind variable](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#inbind) for your date, not `${lastSyncDate}`, since that is a performance and security weakness.